# Function won't return any value when called

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, null

I am trying to create another function that takes all the column names. This function will determine if each variable (data column) is numeric. For each numeric variable, the function will print out the mean he function with your column names. 
This is the head of the dataframe (TitanicDF) I am trying to loop through here.

```
     Survived Pclass    Sex   Age  Fare  Cabin Embarked FamilyNum
        1      1      female  38   71.28   C85        C         1
        1      1      female  35   53.10  C123        S         1
        0      1      male    54   51.86   E46        S         0
        1      3      female   4   16.70    G6        S         2
        1      1      female  58   26.55  C103        S         0
        1      2      male    34   13.00   D56        S         0
```

I have created a for loop that go through all the column name and use a if statament to determine if the column is nummeric

```
name <- colnames(TitanicDF)

func2 <- function(col_names, df){
  for (val in col_names) {
    if (class(val) == "numeric"){
      avg <- mean(df$val)
      print(avg)

    }
  }
}

func2(name, TitanicDF)
```

when i called the function, obviously, the avg for the column age, fare and FamilyNum could be calculated and printed. 
But when I called this function, nothing is returned here. I am really confused here.

Comment: Why not: `summary(df)` or `sapply(df[sapply(df, is.numeric)], mean)`?

Comment: I know this method, but our assignment as us to do it in the easy way without using sapply.  Can you tell me just why there is no output when calling my function here?

Comment: Interesting course or instructor. The apply family is one of R's most basic signature methods. Anyhow in your `if` use `class(df[[val]])` as now you compare strings not data frame columns. Similarly run `mean(df[[val]])`. Can't pass string into `$` operator.